# Kirchhoff's laws with current source in a circuit

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

[image: The circuit]

Here is a circuit with a resistor, current source and a voltage source. I need to apply Kirchhoff's laws on it (both current and voltage), but I get confused with the current source. What do I do with it, how do I handle a situation with a current source in a circuit?

Thanks

Comment: What quantity do you want to find out??

Comment: This is more of a theoretical question. I need to know/understand how to use it, therefore, I would just be glad if you could set up the equations and explain why did you set them up that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\$i\$ is the current in the loop in clockwise direction. Then,
$$-V_{I_1} + iR_1 + V_1 = 0\tag{KVL}$$
$$i = I_1\tag{KCL}$$

where, \$V_{I_1}\$ is the voltage across current source. Then from KCL and KVL,

$$V_{I_1} = V_1+I_1R_1$$